# Delphi Xe6 Android - Google Maps Pin text import in editbox

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I am working on simple app that: 
 1. Loads google map with several location pins within android mobile browser. 
 2. When user taps on some pin I show him pin text (infowindow) and pin text is actually a phone number.
That works ok.

Is it possible to import pin text content from mobile browser to editbox on some form when user taps on pin? 
Then I can let user initiate phone call using the number from editbox

Comment: i'm looking forward for the answer